# join tables sql

Tags: sql, database, join

I have the following tables 
[image]
Dishes table:

[image]

Category table:
[image]

t_time table:
[image]

To get connect a dish with the ingredients I have the following code which works:

```
$sql = "SELECT d.name, i.item\n"
    . "FROM dish d\n"
    . "JOIN dish_ingredients di ON ( d.id = di.dish_id )\n"
    . "JOIN ingredients i ON ( di.ingredient_id = i.id )\n"
    . "WHERE d.id =1\n"
    . "LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

but now I want to connect the dish with the matching `categories`/`t_time` and `cuisine` . instead of having time= 6 and Category 3 being displayed when I do the query I want it to display 60 and fish instead. What would be the easiest way to do this?  a good tutorial might help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just join the tables just like the way you are doing.

```
SELECT  d.name, i.item,
        c.category,
        e.cuisine,
        f.t_time
FROM    dish d
        INNER JOIN dish_ingredients di ON ( d.id = di.dish_id )
        INNER JOIN ingredients i ON ( di.ingredient_id = i.id )
        INNER JOIN categories c ON (d.category = c.id)
        INNER JOIN cuisine e ON d.cuisine = e.id
        INNER JOIN t_time f ON d.time = f.id
WHERE   d.id =1
-- LIMIT 0 , 30
```

If it is possible that a dish can have *nullable* values on `category`, `cuisine`, and `t_time`, use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. Basically, `INNER JOIN`  displays row on which it has at least one match on the table on which you have joined while the `LEFT JOIN` displays even if it has no rows on the other table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT d.name, i.item, cat.category, t.t_time, cu.cuisine
FROM dish d
INNER JOIN dish_ingredients di ON d.id = di.dish_id
INNER JOIN ingredients i ON di.ingredient_id = i.id
INNER JOIN category cat ON d.category = cat.id
INNER JOIN cuisine cu ON d.cuisine = cu.id
INNER JOIN t_time t ON d.t_time = t.id
WHERE d.id = 1
```

Comment: I am trying another table but can't get the member_id to work: 
SELECT d.name, i.item,
c.category,
e.cuisine,
f.t_time,
m.member_id
FROM my_dishes d
INNER JOIN dish_ingredients di ON ( d.id = di.dish_id )
INNER JOIN ingredients i ON ( di.ingredient_id = i.id )
INNER JOIN member m ON ( m.member_id = i.id )
LEFT JOIN category c ON (d.category = c.id)
LEFT JOIN cuisine e ON d.cuisine = e.id
LEFT JOIN t_time f ON d.t_time = f.id
WHERE d.id =1
LIMIT 0, 30

Comment: got it... or something: SELECT d.name, i.item, c.category, e.cuisine, f.t_time, m.id
FROM my_dishes d
INNER JOIN dish_ingredients di ON ( d.id = di.dish_id )
INNER JOIN ingredients i ON ( di.ingredient_id = i.id )
INNER JOIN member m ON ( d.member_id = m.id )
LEFT JOIN category c ON ( d.category = c.id )
LEFT JOIN cuisine e ON d.cuisine = e.id
LEFT JOIN t_time f ON d.t_time = f.id
WHERE d.member_id
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT d.name, i.item, c.category, t.t_time, cs.cuisine\n"
    . "FROM dishes d\n"
    . "JOIN dish_ingredients di ON ( d.id = di.dish_id )\n"
    . "JOIN ingredients i ON ( di.ingredient_id = i.id )\n"
    . "LEFT JOIN category c ON ( c.id = d.category )\n"
    . "LEFT JOIN t_time t ON ( t.id = d.t_time )\n"
    . "LEFT JOIN cuisine cs ON ( cs.id = d.cuisine)\n"
    . "WHERE d.id =1\n"
    . "LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

Try to join to the tables with LEFT JOIN, it will show the category,t_time and cuisine if it exists.

Comment: I'm getting this error from your code: #1054 - Unknown column 'di.category' in 'on clause'